# How is a plane a particular solution plus the span of linearly independent vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I am helping my brother. It's been awhile since I have done linear algebra or Calculus III, but I remember this sounds like ODE's $y=y_c+y_p$.

Problem:

> Suppose $\vec a=[1 \ 0 \ 1]^T, \vec b=[2 \ 7 \ -2]^T, \vec c=[3 \ 1\ 5]^T$ are lying on a plane in the 3D space. Prove that $\vec d=[4 \ 8 \ 2]^T$ also lies on that plane.

Hint:

> A plane can be expressed as a particular solution plus the span of linearly independent vectors.

Considering that the 3 given vectors are linearly independent and thus span $\mathbb R^3$, what is a plane that they lie on?

What does the hint mean here?

My brother was not taught cross product yet.

Comment: Hint: the linear span must include the zero vector.

Comment: The vector equation of a plane in 3D has the form $p = p_0+s(p_1-p_0)+t(p_2-p_0)$ where $p_0, p_1$ and $p_2$ are 3 non-colinear points on the plane and s, t are parameters. So any point on the plane is some fixed point plus multiples of directions in the plain (your span).

Comment: @Paul Can the 3 vectors $\vec a=[1 \ 0 \ 1]^T, \vec b=[2 \ 7 \ -2]^T, \vec c=[3 \ 1\ 5]^T$ lie on the same plane in $\mathbb R^3$? $\vec c$ is not in the span of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$. What's happening? I take to understand that $\vec c$ would be the $\vec r$ and $\vec 0$ would be the $\vec r_0$ in the equation that was [given on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Describing_a_plane_with_a_point_and_two_vectors_lying_on_it) $\vec r-\vec r_0=s\vec v+t\vec w$ This looks like yours but in vectors instead of points. Thank you!

Comment: @SeanRoberson So in $\vec r-\vec r_0=s\vec v+t\vec w$, $\vec r_0=0$?

Comment: @Paul Do the vectors span $\mathbb R^3$ because they are all linearly independent? Then it that case, what does this mean? What's the plane that is spanned by 3 linearly independent vectors?

Comment: @SeanRoberson (same question asked to Paul) Do the vectors span $\mathbb R^3$ because they are all linearly independent? Then it that case, what does this mean? What's the plane that is spanned by 3 linearly independent vectors?

Comment: On the Wikipedia page, $r_0$ can be your $a$. The other two vectors can be $v=(b-a)$ and $w=(c-a)$. The vector $r$ is an arbitrary point on the plane, which can be your $d$. You need to show that $(d-a)$ is a linear combination of $(b-a)$ and $(c-a)$, which is equivalent to the Wiki equation $$d=a+s(b-a)+t(c-a)$$.

Comment: @mr_e_man You mean the interpretation is that the terminal points of the vectors are on the plane rather than that the vector from the origin to the terminal point is on the plane?

Comment: Yes, that's the only reasonable interpretation, because $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c$ (considered as line segments from the origin) do not share any plane.

Comment: @mr_e_man Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My brother got clarification:

The vectors do not lie on a plane. The terminal points of the vectors lie on a plane.

mr_e_man and Chris Custer are right.