# When a third vector in a plane does not lie in the span of 2 linearly independent vectors in the plane

Tags: matrices, vectors, vector-analysis, plane-geometry

For instance, can the 3 vectors $\vec a=[1, \ 0, \ 1]^T, \vec b=[2, \ 7, \ -2]^T, \vec c=[3, \ 1,\ 5]^T$ lie on the same plane in $\mathbb R^3$?

My understanding is that the span of 2 linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ such as $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ is a plane that passes through $\vec 0$. Yet $\vec c$ is not in the span of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$. What's happening?

I can see $a^Tb=0$. Is that relevant? [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Describing_a_plane_with_a_point_and_two_vectors_lying_on_it), "Note that v and w can be perpendicular, but cannot be parallel." I take to understand that $\vec c$ would be the $\vec r$ and $\vec 0$ would be the $\vec r_0$ in the equation that was given $\vec r-\vec r_0=s\vec v+t\vec w$

(This is an edit to add a new idea): Do the vectors span $\mathbb R^3$ because they are all linearly independent? Then it that case, what does this mean? What's the plane that is spanned by 3 linearly independent vectors?

Comment: I assume you mean $[1,0,1]$, not $[101]$, and $[2,7,-2]$, not $[27-2]=[25]$.

Comment: @mr_e_man Yes. I thought spacing would helping. Anyway, I put commas. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should look at the distinction between linear subspaces and affine subspaces. A plane is determined by 3 points. The 3 points $\vec0,\vec a,\vec b$ determine a plane, which is a linear subspace. The 3 points $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c$ determine a plane, which is an affine subspace. The 4 points $\vec0,\vec a,\vec b,\vec c$ determine the entire 3D space.

Comment: @mr_e_man Can you help me here? [How is a plane a particular solution plus the span of linearly independent vectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944504/how-is-a-plane-a-particular-solution-plus-the-span-of-linearly-independent-vecto)

Comment: An affine subspace is a linear subspace displaced from the origin. The "particular solution" is that displacement.

Comment: To reinforce the comment by @mr_e_man, it really depends on what you mean by the vectors lying in a plane. If you’re talking about the _points_ for which the vectors are displacement vectors from the origin, then every three noncolinear points determine a unique plane, which might not include the origin. If, on the other hand you’re talking about a _subspace_ of $\mathbb R^3$, then we’re talking about whether or not the vectors are all parallel to some plane through the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with a vector in $\mathbb R^3$ not being in the span of two linearly independent vectors,  since $\mathbb R^3$ is $3$ dimensional, whereas the span of the two vectors will be only $2$ dimensional,  i.e. a plane.

Comment: Thank you! I just figured out that the vectors span $\mathbb R^3$. So what is the "plane" formed by 3 vectors than span $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: $\mathbb  R^3$ itself;  though it is not usually called a "plane".

Comment: Chris Custer, can you help me here? [How is a plane a particular solution plus the span of linearly independent vectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944504/how-is-a-plane-a-particular-solution-plus-the-span-of-linearly-independent-vecto)

Comment: Sure.  This can always be done.   The basic idea is that any plane can be considered a translation of a plane through the origin.

Comment: Any plane through the origin is a subspace,  so it's the span of two linearly independent vectors,  and you get your result.

Comment: ChrisCuster so the plane of a,b and c is the translation by c of the span of a and b? so the plane is $r = s \vec a + t \vec b + c$?

Comment: Almost.   The vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are parallel to the plane.  So they can be gotten, for instance, by taking the difference of pairs of points on the plane.

Comment: I'm confused. Is there a plane that the 3 vectors lie in? If yes, then what please is the plane equation? mr_e_man says there is none. [a⃗ ,b⃗ ,c⃗ (considered as line segments from the origin) do not share any plane. – mr_e_man 50 mins ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944504/how-is-a-plane-a-particular-solution-plus-the-span-of-linearly-independent-vecto)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84133/discussion-between-chris-custer-and-jack-bauer).